# Closures in go: different output on named return value

Tags: go

Consider the following function:

```
func main() {
  var a int = 3
  sum := func() {a = a*2}
  sum()
  sum()
  fmt.Println(a) // returns 12
}
```

However:

```
func main() {
  var a int = 3
  sum := func() (a int) {a = a*2; return}
  sum()
  sum()
  fmt.Println(a) // returns 3
}
```

I can't fully understand logic of this behavior: why it would return old value of `a` after `a = a*2`

Comment: *I can't fully understand logic of this behavior*: You're shadowing the variable `a`; what's confusing about that?

Comment: @TimCooper: `Go's return values may be named. If so, they are treated as variables defined at the top of the function.` This clarifies issue. It is not ideomatic closure behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Like @TimCooper commented, you are shadowing "a".

If you run the code below, you will see two different memory addresses.

It means that are "2 variables a".

The "a" inside sum() represents it's own return, and it's declared without a value, so the compiler assigns the "zero value" to the "other a", that is 0 to numeric types.

So, a = a * 2 is equals 0 = 0 * 2.

When the sum() ends, it returns the "other a" (remember the different memory address?), keeping the "first a" unchanged.

This link might be helpful:
[Go zero values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a int = 3
    sum := func() (a int) {
        fmt.Println(&a) // func sum() scope (a's copy memory address)
        a = a * 2
        return
    }
    b := sum()      // initializing b with the sum() return
    fmt.Println(&a) // func main() scope (a's memory address)
    fmt.Println(b)  // func sum() return
    fmt.Println(a)  // old value, stills 3
}
```